# When mul() is a non static method why is direct call to mul method from sum() allowed without an instance variable

Tags: java, oop, static

When `mul()` is a non static method why is direct call to `mul` method from `sum()` allowed without an instance variable

```
package oops;

public class MethodAccess {

    public void sum(int a, int b) {
        mul(8, 9);
    }

    public void mul(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a * b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodAccess obj = new MethodAccess();
        obj.sum(3, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `sum()` is also non-static, meaning `mul()` is called on the same instance that `sum()` was called on.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you also point me to where i can read more about this please.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling an instance method (`mul`) from another instance method (`sum`) without specifying on which instance to execute the method, the method is executed on the current instance (the one for which you called the original method).

```
public void sum(int a, int b) {
    mul(8, 9);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void sum(int a, int b) {
    this.mul(8, 9);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you also point me to where i can read more about this please.

Comment: Also, i am trying to access mul from main method why cant i access using the same instance just after i have used that instance variable to access sum?

package oops;

public class MethodAccess {

 public void sum(int a, int b) {
  System.out.println(a+b);
 }

 public void mul(int a, int b) {
  System.out.println(a * b);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  MethodAccess obj = new MethodAccess();
  obj.sum(3, 4);
  mul(6,7);

 }

}

Comment: @user10110218 `main` is a static method, so in order to call an instance method from it, you must specify the instance on which it should be called - `obj.mul(6,7);`